# Application of Central Limit Theorem for geometrical random variables

Tags: probability

$X_1,...$ are independent random variables such that each of them has $Geom(0.5)$ distribution.  What can we conclude from Central Limit Thorem for $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i \ge 2k\right)$ ?

I have a problem with understanding this theorem. Can anyone helpe me understand this theorem on this example, please ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two conventions for geometric random variables; one counts trials, the other one counts failures. From the context I think you are using the number of trials; the answer changes a bit if it is the other convention.

Anyway, the mean and variance of a Geom(p) distribution under this convention are $1/p$ and $(1-p)/p^2$ respectively. Plugging in $p=1/2$ you have $2$ and $2$ respectively. Thus the distribution of a sum of $k$ iid Geom(0.5) variables has mean $2k$ and variance $2k$. So $P(\sum_{i=1}^k X_i \geq 2k)$ for large $k$ behaves like $P(Z \geq 0)$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. I got $0$ from $\frac{2k-2k}{\sqrt{2k}}$. Thus it converges to $1/2$.

In effect CLT is telling us that the distribution eventually looks symmetric about its mean (even though the original Geom(p) distribution is not at all symmetric about its mean).